# can windows 10 technical preview be used commercially ?

Tags: windows, license, windows-10-preview

i know windows technical preview is not ready and full of bugs, but i just need to ask are we allowed to use for commercial Purposes or is it only for **Personal/Non-Commercial** use only ?

Comment: This is a legality question, which is not on-topic for SU. The EULA you agreed to when you installed it should spell it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly they want input from business customers as well. There is a [Windows 10 Enterprise Technical Preview forum](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=507624) specifically for this purpose.

As you already know, it would be a hassle to use a technical preview in a corporate environment for standard users.

- It is not a stable OS
- There will be lots of updates
- Not all peripherals (printers) are supported

> Unexpected PC crashes could damage or even delete your files, so you
>   should back up everything. Some printers and other hardware might not
>   work, and some software might not install or work correctly, including
>   antivirus or security programs. You might also have trouble connecting
>   to home or corporate networks.

[source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-faq)

Comment: It also will expire after a period of time.  While its possible the license key could be changed before that date, its a hassle you would have to deal with.